# Does Ableton live have a revert to last saved version feature?

Tags: ableton-live

Say I didn't like the latest changes and would like to get back to the last saved version,
Is there a better / faster way than reopening?
(as by clicking F12 in photoshop, for instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've found someone already asking for that feature on ableton forums:
https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=118351
Guess the answer is no.

Comment: This is correct - there's no such feature in Live.

Comment: Is there really a need to be faster than simply re-opening? You could always use CTRL-O... I would think that it would kinda suck to have a button that could do away with all my changes since the last save version with one single press. A DANGEROUS button, that would be and one I would not care to risk having around, just to save like 1 or 2 clicks. no, really you could hold down undo (CTRL-Z) until it stopped. ;)

Comment: Users of photoshop / revision control programmers are used to this feature :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were connected to splice while making the track …

1) Go to the splice home page while logged in.

2) There, you can see all of your previously saved versions.

3) Click on one, the next page should give you the option to 'open in ableton'

All my master effects disappeared on me and I accidentally saved it. This works I tried it.